# Recursively calling function in scheme with let

Tags: recursion, scheme

Is it possible, in scheme, to do something like the following?

```
(define (foo a b c d e)
  (let ((recurse (foo a b c (bar d) e))
    (if (= d e)
        #f
        (recurse))))
```

I have a function with a rather lengthy set of arguments and some conditions that recursively call it and it's rather unsightly, I'd like to be able to shorthand it.

I've tried this a few different ways but I either get an infinite loop (I presume let is eagerly evaluating) or I get bad let form errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a thunk:

```
(define (foo a b c d e)
  (let ((recurse (lambda () (foo a b c (bar d) e))))
    (if (= d e)
        #f
        (recurse))))
```

This then permits you to add arguments if some but not all of the parameters change.

Comment: But is it worth it? why not just save the value? OP's error was with let's syntax.

Comment: Can't just save the value as that is what results in infinite recursion. The code must run conditionally so it must be delayed with a thunk.

Comment: That did the trick.  I'm too used to Haskell's full lazy evaluation where I can just sprinkle "where" clauses like candy and not think about it

Comment: Why make procedure instead of just having `(foo a b c (bar d) e)` as the alternative? It makes no sense.

Comment: @Sylwester Infinite recursion. Without the thunk to delay, control would never get to the conditional to stop at the base case.

Comment: This partially emulates lazy evaluation.  See SFRI-45 for a more complete implementation of delay and force with memoized thunks (I would rather not call them either promises or futures as both of those imply more than is needed here). In that one would replace `(lambda () x)` with `(delay x)` and `(n)` with `(force n)`.

Comment: @DanD. If you do `(if (= d e) #f (foo a b c (bar d) e))` eg. put it in the alternative/else part and it will terminate when your code terminates. It will fail if the base case never kicks in. Making a thunk is completely unnecessary since it doesn't use it more than once.

Comment: @Sylwester Only if one could. There is more to the example than the code you see. One does not have to justify illustrating a technique in an example that does not require it for the sake of making it more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the arguments don't change you should consider using named `let`:

```
(define (foo a b c d e)
  (let recurse ((d d))
    (if (= d e)
        #f
        (recurse (cdr d)))))
```

This is basically the same as:

```
(define (foo a b c d e)
  (define (recurse d)
    (if (= d e)
        #f
        (recurse (cdr d))))
  // start recursion
  (recurse d))
```

All the other variables will be available through the closure.